# RVM configuration issue - "Missing RVM environment file"

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm, ruby-1.9.2

First time installing RoR and things are a bit confusing.

I first installed Ruby through `apt-get` only to realize that this is not way to go. After Installing ruby and rails with RVM, I ran into trouble with [Readline](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/). Fixed it by following troubleshooting steps. I thought that I got everyting working. I was wrong.

Now that I opened new shell and typed `$ ruby`, I got:

```
ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/home/user/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180'
```

There is no such file. What has happened? Should I just `rm` my .rvm directory and start anew? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your edit:

> After `rm -rf ~/.rvm` and running `rvm install 1.9.3` I still experienced problems, but after `rvm list` I discovered that default was missing so `rvm alias create default 1.9.3` resolved the issue.

Comment: I upgraded ruby from 2.0.0-p247 to 2.0.0-p451. This error came while using rails command. rails gem was actually not installed in 2.0.0-p451@global gemset. It worked after rails install.